# SQLAlchemy: Multiple foreignKeys of the same type

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class similar to this:

```
class Component(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'components'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    .
    .
    .
    .
    alternate1_id = Column(Integer, foreignkey("components.id"), nullable=True)
    alternate2_id = Column(Integer, foreignkey("components.id"), nullable=True)
    alternate3_id = Column(Integer, foreignkey("components.id"), nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, catalog_number, component_type, manufacturer_pn, description):
            self.catalog_number = catalog_number
            self.component_type = component_type
            self.manufacturer_pn = manufacturer_pn
            self.description = description

    def __repr__(self):
            return "<Component('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')>" % (self.catalog_number,
                                                            self.component_type,
```

alternate1, 2 and 3 are optional fields that point to an alternative component for the current instance.

How can I create three relationships, each one referring to each of the id's?

Comment: I recommend creating a linked table and avoid having nullable foreign keys.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try doing that.

Answer (score 0):

See the example in [handling multiple join paths](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#handling-multiple-join-paths) regarding the `foreign_keys` argument to `relationship`.